# Playing sequence of numbers as sound in JavaScript/Web Audio Api

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to play a sound using Web Audio Api.

My data is sequence of numbers which represents digital level of microphone voltage. (Its just array of numbers, [2348, 2360, 2380, 2354...]). My data is sampled with 3kHz frequency.

Is it possible to play sound from such data using Web Audio Api or some similar framework?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this.  The sound quality may not be great, depending on some details.

Let `data` be the array of numbers that you have.  Then you can do something like:

```
context = new AudioContext({sampleRate: 3000});
b = new AudioBuffer({length: data.length, sampleRate: 3000})
b.copyToChannel(data, 0, 0);
s = new AudioBufferSourceNode(context, {buffer: b})
```

However, it is not required that a browser support sample rates as low
as 3000.  The minimum required rate is 8 kHz.  Thus, the construction
of the AudioContext or AudioBuffer may fail.

Comment: The numbers in the array also need to be normalized to the range [-1, 1]. I think you also need to call `s.start()` to begin playback.

Comment: Yes, I left some details out.  Also need `s.connect(context.destination)` to be able to hear anything.  And the normalization can be done with a gain node after the source node.

Comment: It's more like beep than a sound. Should it be at least close to what is recorded? Or is it expected because of this low sample rate?

Do you know any other tool that would be able to play sound from such data?

Comment: Youi're going to have to provide a lot more information before anyone can say if it should be a beep or not.  A  jsfiddle or codepen or whatever with your example would go a long way.